# Number of ways to connect sets of $k$ vertices in a perfect $n$ -gon

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, recurrence-relation, dynamic-programming, mathematical-programming

This is a **copy** of my post at **Mathexchange.com**, as my question is still not fully answered and I really wanna find a solution to this. Feel free to refer to there for useful comments and partial solutions:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294224/number-of-ways-to-connect-sets-of-k-dots-in-a-perfect-n-gon

Let $Q(n,k)$ be the **number of ways** in which we can **connect** sets of $k$ vertices (dots), in a given perfect $n$-gon, such that no two lines **intersect** at the **interior** of the $n$-gon, and **no vertice** remains **isolated**.

**Intersection** of the lines outisde the $n$-gon is acceptable. Obviously, $k|n$, and $n$ can't be prime because otherwise there will be vertices/dots left unconnected. The $n$-gon itself is an acceptable solution to a connection of $n$ vertices, and in the case of $k>2$, these aren't **lines**, but a set of connected lines, a sort of a network formed by **connected planar graphs with straight edges with $k$ vertices, which are required to be vertices of the $n$-gon itself.**

There must always be $S =\frac nk$ **sets** of **lines**. For $k=2$, there are exactly $\frac nk$ lines, and for $k>2$, there are exactly $\frac nk$, **not lines but sets of such connected planar graphs**.

Take for example $Q(6,2)$. We have a perfect hexagon. By brute-forcing with pencil and paper, I found that there are 5 ways to connect sets of 2 vertices (dots) such that no two lines intersect inside the hexagon and no vertice remains unconnected. Hence, $Q(6,2) = 5$.

The following image depicts the case of $Q(6,2)$:

[image: Q(6,2)]

For generality I ask about any amount of $k$ dots, even though I've recently found the solution for $k=2$.

#### Now let's move one step further:

Let $U(n,k)$ be the number of **unique** ways to connect sets of $k$ dots in a perfect $n$-gon, such that no two lines intersect, **and** rotational symmetry is **neglected**, i.e, every possible arrangement is **unique** and can't be formed by rotating another arrangement in any way. $U(6,2)=2$.
Note that $U(6,2)=2$ because the arrangements of the first line in the image are not unique, and can be formed by rotating one another. The same happens for the second line of arrangements. Hence $U(6,2)=2$.

I'm pretty clueless about both functions $U$ and $Q$, and I couldn't derive an algorithm or formula to any of them. Hence I'm posting this here.

I'm pretty sure there's a **pure combinatorial approach** to this problem, perhaps involving **Polya's Enumeration Theorem (PET)**.
Is there an elegant solution to these functions? Can they even be solved for $k>2$?

Any light shed on any of the functions will be very much appreciable, as I haven't been successful in deriving a formula for any of them. Also, both formulas **and** algorithms will be great!

**I can program in Java and Mathematica.**

Thanks a lot in advance.

#### EDIT - Temporary Solutions + Relevant questions AND progress

$$Q(n,2) = C_{n \over 2}\quad\text{where}\quad C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} {2n\choose n}$$
And $C_n$ denotes the $n$'th **Catalan** number.

Now let us denote $W(n) = U(n,2)$. Can you find a formula for $W(n)$? Perhaps a connection between $Q(n,2)$ and $W(n)$?

Comment: It is generally not recommended to cross-post questions. If your question was not properly answered on http://math.stackexchange.com/ because it is a research problem on combinatorics, it is unlikely to be well received here. You should ask for it to be **migrated**, perhaps to http://mathoverflow.net/.

Comment: @AndréSouzaLemos Perhaps you're right about cross-posting questions. Thing is I think a solution **does** exist, but is just not well known. This is why I'm trying to reach as many people as I can.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it's pure combinatorics (hence mathematics, not computer science) and it has already been posted on [math.se].